# Error with golang while creating sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, go

So I have to create a sqlite table with a golang program so I did this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    database, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./ProjetForum.db")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer database.Close()
    statement, err := database.Prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (UserID integer NOT NULL primary key, Pseudo text NOT NULL , Email text NOT NULL , Rank integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, Phone text , Description text , ArrivingDate integer NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , Key text NOT NULL , Verified integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Banned integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Deleted integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Points integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Staff integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Image blob )")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    statement.Exec()
    statement, erro := database.Prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Posts (PostID integer NOT NULL primary key , Title text NOT NULL , Description text NOT NULL , PublishDate integer NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, Closed integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Verified integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , ReviewID integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Deleted text NOT NULL , ToReview integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Points integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Likes integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , Dislikes integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , UserID integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) references Users(`UserID`)) ")
    if erro != nil {
        log.Fatal(erro)
    }
    statement.Exec()
}
```

And the second one does not want to execute it self the first one is creating itself correctly but the `Post` table can't be created.

Comment: You forgot the keyword DEFAULT before 0 for the column ReviewID and you missed a `,` before the keyword FOREIGN. Also, don't use single quotes around column names. If necessary use backticks or square brackets.

Comment: I am not ignoring the errors it's just that at `log.Fatal(erro)` it is printing `near "foreign" : syntax error`

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? Before FOREIGN you must have a `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for errors when doing `statement.Exec()` as well as that would've pointed you to the actual error.

The problem lies where you do `CURRRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (note number of `R`s in `CURRENT`) and not using the `DEFAULT` keyword for `ReviewID`.

The syntax for creating a table is documented here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: `CURRRENT_TIMESTAMP` although it's a typo, does not throw any error.

Comment: Thank you very much some times it's hard to see our own errors ^^

The foreign key is actually not working as well now